# Why the last plugin which is to generate report for my cucumber Test Scenario run is working

Tags: java, cucumber

Why the last plugin which is to generate report for my cucumber Test Scenario run is working 
Compile - Surefire SkipTest - Mvn-exec-Plgun with java- failsafe-verify
while running it from Maven

```
    <!-- ####### maven-compiler-plugin ######### -->
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                    <!--fork>true</fork-->
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

   <!-- ####### maven-surefire-plugin ######### -->
        <plugin>
```

executions>

```
    </plugin>

<!-- ####### maven-cucumber-reporting ######### -->
        <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                         <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>AutoRunner_Cucumber</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>${project.build.directory}/target/cucumber.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                     </configuration>   
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

 </plugins>
</build>
```